# Macros ( remove spaces within variable)

Tags: sas

I want to create a table like-

```
%let x =ab bc;

Proc sql;
    create table rx_&x as
    select * from test;
quit;
```

Not able to create, have used compress and %str as well.

Comment: So you want your table to be called `rx_abbc`?

Comment: user2877959 is correct. Quote="Blanks cannot appear in SAS names." Ref: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000998953.htm

Comment: Please show how you used compress and what errors you received.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%sysfunc()` in order to use SAS functions in macro code.

```
%let x=ab bc;

proc sql;
create table rx_%sysfunc(compress(&x.)) as
select *
from test
;
quit;
```